# Passing a pointer to template class as a parameter

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I am having trouble passing a template class as a parameter to a another function.
I am using VS2012 c++/cli on a Windows 8.1 machine compiling for x64.

The compiler keeps telling me:

```
 void Channel::TestFunc(SynchQueue<T> *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Channel'
```

SynchQueue is a template class for a multi-threaded queue.  I created it with another class I will call Images.

In my main.cpp, I have:

```
 QPtr = new SynchQueue<Images>;
```

Also in main.cpp, I created a class called WorkerThread to which I passed QPtr.
No problems with that.

Now I want WorkerThread to pass QPtr to another class that is instantiated in WorkerThread.

So I defined the function as:

Channel.h

```
public ref class Channel
{
public:
    // other definition stuff
    void TestFunc(SynchQueue<Images> *tQPtr);
}
```

Channel.cpp

```
void Channel::TestFunc(SynchQueue<Images> *tQPtr)
{
    int x;
    x++;
}
```

I keep getting the error above.  What am I doing wrong?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us your call to TestFunc, as well as the declaration of whatever you're passing to it?

Comment: I did not even call it yet.  Just compiling this gives me an error.

Comment: That sounds like the compiler is unable to match the function declaration and definition. Have you checked for syntax errors which might be causing either one to be parsed incorrectly?

Comment: I have checked that a bunch of times so I do not think that is it.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
template<typename T>
void TestFunc(SynchQueue<T> *tQPtr);
```

Comment: I typed your example in exactly and am getting an error saying: error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition.  I also substituted Images for T in the call and it did not like that either.

Comment: Actually, I see that I made mistake because I thought you were missing a semicolon on the template line.  When I enter this as:  template<typename T> void TestFunc(SynchQueue<T> *tStitchingQPtr);  Now, I get error C2182: 'TestFunc' : illegal use of type 'void'